# Python3 - Use a variables inside string formatter arguments

Tags: python, string, printing, format

I have some formatted columns that I'm printing. I would like to use the following variables to set the lengths in my .format arguments

```
number_length = 5
name_length = 24
viewers_length = 9
```

I have

```
print('{0:<5}{1:<24}{2:<9}'.format(' #','channel','viewers'), end = '')
```

Ideally I would like something like

```
print('{0:<number_length}{1:<name_length}{2:<viewers_length}'.format(
     ' #','channel','viewers'), end = '')
```

But this gives me an invalid string formatter error.

I have tried with % before the variables and parenthesis, but have had no luck.

Comment: Can you share what the desired output would be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to:

1. Wrap the names in braces, too; and
2. Pass the widths as keyword arguments to `str.format`.

For example:

```
>>> print("{0:>{number_length}}".format(1, number_length=8))
       1
```

You can also use dictionary unpacking:

```
>>> widths = {'number_length': 8}
>>> print("{0:>{number_length}}".format(1, **widths))
       1
```

`str.format` won't look in the local scope for appropriate names; they **must** be passed explicitly.

For your example, this could work like:

```
>>> widths = {'number_length': 5,
              'name_length': 24,
              'viewers_length': 9}
>>> template= '{0:<{number_length}}{1:<{name_length}}{2:<{viewers_length}}'
>>> print(template.format('#', 'channel', 'visitors', end='', **widths))
#    channel                 visitors
```

*(Note that `end`, and any other explicit keyword arguments, must come before `**widths`.)*

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it like this

```
In [11]: widths = dict(number=5, name=24, viewers=9)

In [12]: data = ('#', 'channel', 'viewers')

In [13]: '{:<{number}}{:<{name}}{:<{viewers}}'.format(*data, **widths)
Out[13]: '#    channel                 viewers  '
```

Of course, it's also possible to generate the format string, without actually getting it formatted:

```
In [14]: '{{:<{number}}}{{:<{name}}}{{:<{viewers}}}'.format(**widths)
Out[14]: '{:<5}{:<24}{:<9}'
```

Comment: The extra step with doubled braces is potentially superfluous; you can have nested single braces and pass the widths and values to be formatted at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your format string first

```
f = '{0:<%d}{1:<%d}{2:<%d}' % (number_length, name_length, viewers_length)
#produces
'{0:<5}{1:<24}{2:<9}'
```

Then use that in your other format call

```
print(f.format(' #','channel','viewers'), end = ''))
```

Comment: It seems rather odd to mix two different string formatting styles!

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Didn't know you could do this. I also like this because I have to use this formatting more than once, so building it a single time is preferable.