# Dynamically Formatting Floats to Variable Decimal Places Using f-strings in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.6, rounding, f-string

I've previously asked about dynamically adjusting the number of decimal places in a float when formatting with f-strings in Python. While I found similar questions that address aspects of dynamic formatting using f-strings, none specifically tackle the challenge of varying the precision (decimal places) based on a variable.

The closest discussions I found were focused on [insert aspect, e.g., alignment, width, etc.], which isn't quite what I'm struggling with. My goal is to format a float to a number of decimal places that is determined at runtime.

EXAMPLE

```
    n = 5  # The number of decimal places should be dynamic
value = 0.345
# Desired output: '0.34500', but with 'n' determining the number of zeroes
value = 0.345
```

Attempts to directly apply solutions from related questions have not yielded the results I need, as they primarily deal with static formatting or do not address precision directly.

Question: How can I modify the f-string syntax to accommodate a variable that dictates the number of decimal places in the formatted output? I'm looking for a way to make the precision of a floating-point number in an f-string as flexible as the width or alignment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3 - Use a variables inside string formatter arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28330657/python3-use-a-variables-inside-string-formatter-arguments)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This should work:

```
n = 5
value = 0.345
print(f'{value:.{n}f}')
```

**Output:**

```
0.34500
```